# iOS Application with Firebase doesn't start with a slow internet connection

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

Since I upgraded to the new Firebase, my application doesn't start with a slow internet connection. It does when it is has a good connection and also when it hasn't got any connection at all. I think that I've set up everything properly since it wouldn't work at all if I made a mistake with the setup.

Here's my AppDelegate code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't start"? What error message do you get? Also, have you run the time profiler instrument or taken a stackshot while it's hanging to see what the holdup is?

Comment: I mean that the app would crash if I start it with a slow internet connection but it wouldn't when it is connected to the computer. Therefore I don't even get an error message. And I haven't used the timer profiler instrument because I have no idea how it works yet.

Comment: If the app crashes then there is a crash log on the device with an error message. You can also simulate slow Internet on your computer using Network Link Conditioner

Answer (score 2):

iOS includes a mechanism called watchdog, which will terminate any application that fails to launch in a certain time window.  Any blocking task you do in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` has the potential to cause your app to be terminated if it takes too long.  You should consider performing such tasks asynchronously.

You can put breakpoints or print statements in your code to determine which line is taking too long.

Comment: But I need to have the method, which is taking so long in     application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)    . The application wouldn't work otherwise. How can I make the method perform anyway?

Comment: You don't _need_ to have those method calls in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.  You can always defer them to some later point; you would just have to defer using what they setup in your app until that deferred work is finished (i.e., present some kind of loading UI).  It's hard for me to speculate why the methods are taking a long time, but that's a different question anyhow.